# Tcl_AsyncDelete with pynput and pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, pyautogui, pynput

In a simplified version of the code:

```py
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import pyautogui


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.paused = False

    def on_activate(self):
        if self.paused:
            pyautogui.alert(text='was paused', title='title', button='button')
            self.paused = False
        elif self.paused is False:
            pyautogui.alert(text='was not paused', title='title', button='button')
            self.paused = True


test = Test()
pyautogui.alert(text='test', title='title', button='button')
hotkey = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
    '<ctrl>+a': test.on_activate
})
hotkey.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

I will get the error `Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread`.

Now I understand that this comes from issues handling threading, or rather the lack of said handling. I noticed that if the code runs without the alert() below the class declaration; there is never any such error.

I believe I understand that this comes from pynput working on another thread than the first pyautogui call was made; however since I no longer have a use for for alert boxes there is there a way to "properly close" it in that thread and operate it on the other?

I am at a slight loss and any input or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In case of relevance, this is also being run on Windows 10, python V 3.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a workaround solution it seems. The 'solution' as it stands it to simply not use pyautogui for those prompts and to build a unique tkinter box per call for those listener calls. My resulting end code is:

```py
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import pyautogui
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox


def send_alert(text, title):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo(title, text)
    root.destroy()


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.paused = False

    def on_activate(self):
        if self.paused:
            send_alert('paused', 'title')
            self.paused = False
        elif self.paused is False:
            send_alert('not paused', 'title')
            self.paused = True


test = Test()
pyautogui.alert(text='test', title='title', button='button')

hotkey = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
    '<ctrl>+a': test.on_activate
})
hotkey.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```